# (PyQt) Why can't I change the font of my QTextEdit widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Whenever I try to change the font of my QTextEdit widget using the function from the last codeblock, the program crashes instantly with code 1. What could be the reason of it?

```
self.font = QFont("Arial")
```

...

```
self.text_edit = QTextEdit()
self.setCentralWidget(self.text_edit)
self.text_edit.setCurrentFont(self.font)
```

...

```
def aFont(self):
    previous_font = self.font
    self.font = QFontDialog().getFont(previous_font)
    if self.font != previous_font:
        self.text_edit.selectAll()
        self.text_edit.setCurrentFont(self.font)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question lacks a lot of important information, such as the platform and the version of PyQt you are using, and a full traceback. However, assuming you are using PyQt-5.5, it's possible to make a plausible guess at the likely cause of the problem.

In previous versions of PyQt, certain unhandled exceptions would just result in a traceback being printed to stderr without otherwise interrupting execution of the application. But this is not how a normal python script would behave. So the behaviour in has been corrected in PyQt-5.5, in that the application will now immediately abort when encountering an unhandled exception (see [Incompatibilities with Earlier Versions](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/incompatibilities.html#unhandled-python-exceptions) in the PyQt5 docs).

I don't know what you see when you run your application (I'm assuming you're on Windows), but on Linux I see this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in aFont
    self.text_edit.setCurrentFont(self.font)
TypeError: QTextEdit.setCurrentFont(QFont): argument 1 has unexpected type 'tuple'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So the application doesn't "crash" - it just aborts when it encounters the unhandled exception. The specific error is caused by this line:

```
    self.font = QFontDialog().getFont(previous_font)
```

because `getFont` returns a tuple `font, ok` (where `ok` is a boolean indicating whether the user clicked Ok or Cancel). So you just need to change the line to look like this:

```
    self.font, ok = QFontDialog().getFont(previous_font)
```

Comment: Or if we only need the font - `self.font = QFontDialog().getFont(previous_font)[0]`